# Using catkin to install pre-made libraries

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, packages, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to use catkin to hep package some libraries that a project needs. The idea was to have them structured in the following manner:

```
catkin_library
|
+-- lib (contains .so files )
+-- include ( contains header files )
+-- CMakeLists.txt (has catkin_package() and install() )
+-- package.xml ( list all dependencies )
```

I am able to get the header files installed thanks to an answer provided here: [ROS Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/231131/using-catkin-to-install-libraries/) the problem is that it cannot find the libraries I want to link against. Here is an example of a CMakeLists.txt that I am currently using:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.3 )

project( project_lib )

catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS include
                DEPENDS      ProjectLib )

install( DIRECTORY include
         DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION} )

install( FILES lib/ProjectLib.so 
         DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION} )
```

I am not sure how to get the catkin_make process to find and link against the libraries or if this is even a smart way of doing this. I want to provide a workspace that allows the user just to run catkin_make and have it build and install based on the the provided catkin_package and catkin library packages. The idea for how the workspace would look is like this:

```
project_ws 
    + devel
    + build
    + install
    + src
        + project                   (metapakcage)
        + project_exe               (catkin ros package)
        + project_msgs              ( ros msgs and services )
        + project_libraries         (metapackage)
            + project_libraries     (metapackage)
            + project_lib_1         ( external pre-built library )
            + project_lib_2         ( external pre-built library )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231199/using-catkin-to-install-pre-made-libraries/) by [badrobit](https://answers.ros.org/users/25254/badrobit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's possible but it's rather complicated, particularly if your package needs to support multiple architectures such as 32-bit Intel, 64-bit intel and ARM.

Have a look at https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_gige_sdk/blob/hydro-devel/CMakeLists.txt for an example.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2